# Parse a file to find all the carriage return '\r' in it using python

Tags: python

I have a python script that does the following:

1) It writes print "hi",chr(13),chr(13),"bi" to a file.
2) when I do f.read() I see the following on shell: 'hi **\r\r**bi'

However in the file it is written 'hi bi'.
What I want to do is:
Count the number of carriage return '\r' and print it on shell.
Also I would like to replace the substring '\r\r' with the string 'abcde'.
code snippet:
`f=open('out2.txt','rb')
sub='\r\r'
print str.count(sub,1,25)`

Can anyone suggest how this can be done in python??

Comment: Have you look at `str.count` and `str.replace`?

Comment: Yes it does not recognize '\r' because in the file actually the string 'hi bi' is seen. '\r' is a non-printable character is probably the reason for this.

Comment: Are you working with MacOS and opening files with binary mode, right?

Comment: I am working on windows 7 and opening the file as: f= open('test.txt','rb')... 'b' used for binary.

Comment: I see. So only you have to do is to read file binary-by-binary and count the number of '\r', I think.

Comment: yes..but it's not working.

Comment: What is your code like? Editing your question with your code helps to understand your problem more.

Answer (score 0):

To just count the number of specific characters in the file, you should open the file with ascii mode (not binary mode).

```
def count_str(file, s):
    ans = 0
    with open(file, 'r') as fp:
        ans = fp.read().count(s)
    return ans
```

If you have to open the file with binary mode, the code is like follwing,

```
def count_str_binary(file, s):
    ans = 0
    with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
        buf = fp.read()
        bufsize = len(buf)
        length = len(s)
        for i in range(bufsize - length + 1):
            ok = True
            for j in range(length):
                if buf[i + j] != ord(s[j]):
                    ok = False
                    break
            if ok:
                ans += 1
    return ans
```

Comment: In the code above, **c** can be both character and string but int the code below, **c** can be only character.

Comment: @tatsy, It can not be string. Because `ord()` is only applicable for characters

Comment: I revised the code below to accept also strings. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Thanks @tatsy for your help the problem is resolved.